# Stack Overflow policy to handle answers of question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, answers, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

The question may give several correct answers, but none of them is complete. Does Stack Overflow check all the answers and does it make a summary of them to show it as the accepted answer? What is the policy of Stack Overflow to handle the answers of a question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Kop et al Not clear how this is a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have misunderstood how SO works - there is no single entity called "StackOverflow", just a bunch of people asking, answering and voting. There is thus no-one to "check" an answer (and even if there were, how could they do it?) or make a summary (though people can do that if they want - very few do seem to want), and there is no real policy, (except what emerges by general concensus). Welcome to true democracy (or social anarchism, if you prefer).

Comment: If you have an *El Presidente* it is called *dictatorship* in the western world.